# What OOP techniques are used in this code? Is it aggregation, composition, generalization, association or just dependency?

Tags: python, oop, tkinter

I would like to ask whether the aggregation or dependency is used in this code? In other words, how is class `StartPage()` dependant on the class `SeaofBTCapp`?

```
import tkinter as tk

class SeaofBTCapp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self)

        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)

        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}
        frame = StartPage(container, self)
        self.frames[StartPage] = frame
        frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Start Page")
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

app = SeaofBTCapp()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: It seems like aggregation, since `SeaofBTCapp` contains a collection of `StartPage` instances in `self.frames`

Comment: It seems that `class StartPage` is not dependant on the class `SeaofBTCapp`.

Comment: @Barmar: `SeaofBTCapp` contains a dictionary of `tk.Frame` sublcasses, `StartPage` being one of them — but I think you're right about it being aggregation,

Comment: @BryanOakley Someone else already said that 2 days ago.

Comment: I suspect the aggregation here is only non-obvious because there's *also* a reference to the container `SeaofBTCapp` passed into `StartPage` as its `parent`. So the objects sort of both contain (references to) each other!

Answer (score 0):

> how is class StartPage() dependant on the class SeaofBTCapp?

`StartPage` is designed to act as a single page in a multi-page app. It requires that some other object or program is responsible for creating it and causing it to be displayed. Loosly speaking, this is a view in the *model, view, controller* pattern.

`SeaofBTCapp` is a class designed to display one page at a time, where pages are implemented as frames composed of one or more additional widgets. It acts as the controller in the *model, view, controller* pattern.

Using your terminology, `SeaofBTCapp` is an *aggregated* object since it is composed of many pages.

Comment: Isn't it then composition since `StartPage` cannot exist independently without  `SeaofBTCapp`?

Comment: @Eitas: `StartPage` _can_ exist independently without `SeaofBTCapp`. As it is currently implemented, I can take `StartPage` out and use  it in my own program if I need a frame that has a label in it. Though, if `StartPage` were more complex and depended on resources supplied by `SeaofBTCapp` then it would be composition.

Comment: So, if in `StartPage` I used any method from `SeaofBTCapp`, would it be composition?